# How to call a function of type Ptr GLubyte -> IO() in Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell, ffi

In the OpenGL Raw library is the following function:

```
glPolygonStipple :: Ptr GLubyte -> IO ()
```

The C counterpart to this function accepts a pointer to an array, but how can I call this function with an array/list in a Haskell program?

Comment: You'll probably need [one of these functions](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Ptr+a+-%3E+IO+b%29+-%3E+IO+b).

Comment: Thanks. The code I came up with:   withStorableArray xs glPolygonStipple

Answer (score 5):

You'll use mallocArray to allocate memory and pokeArray to put your list into it:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html#v:mallocArray

Something like:

```
do
  arrayOfGLuBytes <- (mallocArray 15) :: IO (Ptr GLubyte)
  pokeArray arrayOfGLuBytes [1,2,3,4]
  glPolygonStipple arrayOfGLuBytes
  free arrayOfGLuBytes -- free from Foreign.Marshall.Alloc
```

Comment: I think you need to also do a `Foreign.Marshall.Alloc.free arrayOfGLuBytes` once you are done.  (Not sure whether OpenGL takes ownership of the array that it is passed.  If it does, ignore this comment)

Comment: Yes, you're right :) 
Thanks, adding it to the answer. Thinking in C inside Haskell code sometimes makes us bypass C's lowlevel style.

Comment: Best is to use `allocaArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best way to go in this situation is storable vectors in the vector package [http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable.html][1]. Package provide rich interface for both immutable and mutable vectors so don't have to create vectors inside IO monad. Besides lists are linked list and conversion to arrays inovlve copying

You particular example could looks like

```
let myVector = fromList [1,2,3,4] 
in unsafeWith myVector glPolygonStipple
```